# Serialized object POST'd using the ServiceStack client is null

Tags: c#, rest, servicestack

I am building a restful service in C# using service stack.

Here is my service implementation.

```cs
namespace cloudfileserver
{   
    [Route("/updatefile", "POST")]
    public class UpdateFile
    {
        public UserFile file { get; set; }
    }

    public class CloudFileService : Service
    {
        public InMemoryFileSystem filesystem { get; set; }
        private static readonly log4net.ILog logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger (typeof(CloudFileService));

        public void Post (UpdateFile request)
        {
            try{
                logger.Debug("File received is :"  + request.file);
                filesystem.addFileSynchronized (request.clientId, request.file);
            }catch(Exception e){
                logger.Debug(e);
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling this service through the following servicestack client code :

```cs
JsonServiceClient client  = new JsonServiceClient(ENDPOINT);
UpdateFile arg = new UpdateFile();
UserFile file = new UserFile ("x.txt", "piyush");
file.SetFileContent (getByteArrayFromString ("Filecontent"), 0);
arg.file = file;
client.Post<Object>("/updatefile", arg);
```

The issue is that whenever I make a post call through the above client code, the file object received is NULL on the server end (which I verify by writing it to the log file).

[Here is the `File` class](http://pastebin.com/F0g5cpGk) which is being sent over the wire. 
The `File` class is `serialisable` since I can correctly send it through a `GET` call.

Any idea what might be going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested your scenario, and can't reproduce the issue you are having. I would recommend you verify your `SetFileContent` method and the `getByteArrayFromString` method, as you may have an error there. Feel free to post that implementation.

Further to that it would be useful if you captured the HTTP request that is made to the server, to determine where the problem lies.

Below is the fully working source code for a self-hosted ServiceStack v4 test application, that uses the implementation you outlined, I hope this helps.

```cs
using System;
using ServiceStack;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace v4
{
    class MainClass
    {
        // Assumed implementation of your getByteArrayFromString
        static byte[] getByteArrayFromString(string path)
        {
            return System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            // Simple Self-Hosted Console App
            var appHost = new AppHost(500);
            appHost.Init();
            appHost.Start("http://*:9000/");

            // Test the service
            string filename = "image.png";
            JsonServiceClient client  = new JsonServiceClient("http://localhost:9000");

            // Create and set the file contents
            UserFile file = new UserFile (filename, "username");
            file.SetFileContent(getByteArrayFromString(filename), 0);

            // Post the file
            client.Post<Object>("/updatefile", new UpdateFile { file = file } );

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class AppHost : AppHostHttpListenerPoolBase
    {
        public AppHost(int poolSize) : base("Test Service", poolSize, typeof(TestService).Assembly) { }
        public override void Configure(Funq.Container container) { }
    }

    [Route("/updatefile","POST")]
    public class UpdateFile
    {
        public UserFile file { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class UserFile 
    {

        public string filepath { get; set;}
        public string owner { get; set;}
        public byte[] filecontent { get; set;}
        public long filesize { get; set;}
        public List<string> sharedwithclients { get; set;}
        public long versionNumber {get;set;}
        object privateLock = new object();

        public UserFile (string filepath, string owner)
        {      
            this.filepath = filepath;
            this.owner = owner;
            versionNumber = -1;
            filesize = 0;
            filecontent = new byte[0];
            sharedwithclients = new List<string>();
        }

        public void SetFileContent(byte[] contents, long version)
        {
            filecontent = contents;
            filesize = filecontent.Length;
            versionNumber = version;
        }
    }

    public class TestService : Service
    {
        public void Post(UpdateFile request)
        {
            // Request is populated correctly i.e. not null.
            Console.WriteLine(request.file.ToJson());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Scott. Even if there is some issue with SetFileContent ( it's just an setter method) and getByteArrayFromString, that should effect the members of the file class. The problem is that the file object being received is null. Also I am sending the File Object directly in my post call while you are sending an object of UpdateFile. Is there an difference?

Comment: @Piyush No setting `new UpdateFile { file = file }` or using your `args` object doesn't make any difference. The sample code I have there works. So there is something odd with your implementation. Can you try running it, and seeing if it works. Just create a new console app, add ServiceStack package and copy the code from above. Put a file named image.png in the bin folder, or point the file path in the code to somewhere useful. Alternatively as I mentioned you can debug by using an HTTP monitoring tool such as [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

Comment: @Piyush Also what version of ServiceStack are you using i.e 4.019? Are you testing locally? What size is the file you are testing with, do you use a proxy? Any other relevant configuration information.

Comment: @Piyush Did you get this sorted? If not it would be great if you could provide more information so I can try closing this issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot Scott it seems to be working now. You can close. Although I am not quite sure what was wrong earlier. I will update this thread if I find out.

Comment: I think I might know the reason of this not working. I had define the UpdateFile class twice - once in service and once in client. And the name of the field file was not the same, which was causing it not to be set. I didn't know that the matching is done using names.

Comment: @Piyush Ah yes that that will do it. Glad you got it working. :)

Comment: So does the marshalling and unmarshalling happen by matching the field names?